# How to use Environment File in SSIS Job Step Property

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-job

Created a package and deployed on SQL Server 2017. my package is having parameters (package level scope) and want to set values from environment file at the time of create a SQL-JOB-STEP.

I have created environment file and defined my variables perfectly **"Integration Services Categolog => SSISDB => MyProject => Environments"** and those variables can be assigned at the time of configure & execute to my package parameters which is working well.

but I cannot do the same while create SQL-JOB. I can see in "step properties window" there is a option to locate "Environment" file but when I locate the file then I cannot find the way to assign those variables to my package's parameters. can anyone help me in this please?

please refer picture:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Click the ellipses (...) besides the empty Value spot. There you will be presented with three options (if you didn't have an Environment established, there'd be only two).

The design time value is the default here. If your parameter, MyVar01_PackageLevel, had an actual value displayed, the UI would render it in the default font weight/style.

One row above is a manual override radio button and here you can just hard code the value. Doing this will result in the Value displayed to be in bold

One row below the design time value is where you can associate a parameter to a list of parameter values from your Environment. Scroll through the list of values, which are in no discernible order, and find the target property name. Let's call it `V01_PL` After selecting that, the above will indicate V01_PL in an italicized font. It won't show the value of `V01_PL` mind you, it'll just tell you it's driven the configured value.

Comment: Fairly certain that is how the screens are represented but I don't have an SSIS project handy to verify the precise names but you ought to be able to work from the above text

Comment: "which are in no discernible order". Right? And what is _that_ about? I'd +2 if I could.

Comment: @EricBrandt "Closed, won't fix" was the response to my Connect item. :'(

Comment: @billinkc thank you for answer & its works! to help others here is what exactly i did, first I assigned my parameter value by selecting environment variable at design-time in Integration Services Catalogs.  and than, in the Job-Setup-property I just checked "Environments:" option and system is rendering assigned variables automatically as required!  thanks to all.